# VB6 KeyDown Fails to Cancel the Keypress

Tags: vb6

I'm trying to detect when the user presses certain keys in a text box and then I want to increase or decrease the value in the text according to their keypress and cancel out the key they pressed. The cancel part isn't working. I'm accustomed to just putting in KeyCode = 0 if I want to cancel their keypress, like I do in MS Access. However, this isn't working for me in VB6. The plus sign gets into the textbox.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd say ignore the `KeyDown` event and just use the `KeyPress` event:

```
Private Sub RTB_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)

    ' "Cancel" the keystroke   
    KeyAscii = 0

End Sub
```

The best way to do what you're doing, though, would be to set your form's `KeyPreview` property to `True`, and then add a handler for the form's `KeyPress` event - this means the form gets a chance to handle any keystrokes first.  By handling it here and cancelling as above, you can change the text in the textbox however you like.

I used Visual Basic for the first 10 years of my career, but I had to google for the above code.  I recommend at least moving on to VB.NET - sometimes you can even import VB6 projects into .NET (sometimes).

Comment: I did VB.NET for a year, and then C# for 5-6 years. C# was difficult at first, but I quickly learned the benefits of a relatively strict compiler. It is possible to write simple, clean, reliable code in pre-.NET Visual Basic, but the language/framework does absolutely nothing to help you get there.

Answer (score -1):

```
Private Sub Text1_KeyUp(KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, Shift As Integer)
  If KeyCode = 27 Then
    'CONDITION
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: It would be good to format the code and add explanatory text.

Comment: I guess `MSForms.ReturnInteger` is from VBA, not from VB6?